How to create release pipeline for a static web app on azure devops?
I want to create a static web app which consists of html,css, javascript files using release pipelines. I tried setting up the jobs using azure web app but it is not getting authorised. I need an alternative method ?
Creation and successful execution of release pipelines. The Expectation is to deploy the static web app on to azure portal for a specific component and make sure it doesn't affect other pipelines.

Assuming you have imported the code of this sample React Azure Static Web App into one of your Azure Repos and you would use a release pipeline in your Azure DevOps organization to deploy the app to Azure, here are the brief steps for your reference.

Create a new release pipeline and add the Static Web App repo as the release pipeline artifacts;

Click on the Agent Job and switch to use the ubuntu-latest agent from the Microsoft-hosted agent pool;

Add the AzureStaticWebApp@0 task under the Agent job of Stage 1 with the paths and token updated similar to the marks in the image below;

Copy out the deployment token the from your target static web app and use it to define the variable $(APIToken) in the release pipeline;



Then you may create a new release to test the deployment to Azure.
